# the listing of values in a column that correspond to a specific value in another column in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

the source data is in the following format

```
    A   B
    1   0
    2   0
    4   1
    5   0
    6   0
    8   1
```

I originally intended to list the missing items in the column A but since that did not quite work out for me, I intend to achieve the same thing via the method I will propose now.

What I want is a list that goes

```
    C
    3
    7
```

essentially giving me the missing numbers of the sequence by using the values provided in the column B. But basically any solution that would give me the values listed under column C would be very appreciated.

It should be noted that I am working with a large list so that manual filtering and such are not preferable.

Comment: @simoco I've tried incorporating several VBA scripts and formulae that would, in theory, directly give me column C. Those can be found [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1054-excel-identify-missing-numbers-sequence.html) in a rather compact form.

Comment: that is a mistake by my part, will fix now.

Comment: The formula "Identify missing numbers sequence with an array" on the page you provided seems to do exactly what you want.  Did you try it?

Comment: I have, but it just does not work. Trying the proposed method for a short list of, say 10 numbers, it worked. Surprisingly and confusingly, it did not work for a list of around 100 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column `B` is not needed (it can be computed from `A`), assuming that you have the data on sheet named `worksheet1`, the VBA sub that writes all the missing values to column `C` is the following:

```
Sub worksheet1c()
    'this contains the position in column A
    Dim i As Integer
    'this contains the position in column C
    Dim j As Integer
    'the numbers from 1
    Dim number As Integer

    'initialization
    i = 1
    j = 1
    number = 1

    'check all numbers in column A from row 2
    Do While Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        'if there is a difference between number and the value in cell write them to column C
        Do Until number = Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = number
            j = j + 1
            number = number + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
        number = number + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: your suggestion results in a list of numbers starting with the first missing number there is. example conforming the initial case presented by myself: `3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...` and goes on until overflow.

Comment: I tried it again (and corrected it to start from 1st row). It stops when finds an empty cell in column `A`. With numbers `1 2 4 5 6 8 13`, it writes `3 7 9 10 11 12`to column `C` and stops because the 8th cell in column `A` is empty. It does not go until overflow. Are you using decimals? Then you should use `Do Until number >= Sheets("worksheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value`.

Comment: I actually got your sub to work alas there are some problems that were not stated above in the original question. So, I will consider this one answered. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I you open another queston with the existing problems not stated above here, please share a link to it, maybe I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

In cell **G4** enter an address you want to look in, for example **A2:A5** and then use the array formula below. The only assumption is that the list of numbers should begin from **1**. I know it looks crazy, the formula. This formula has to be applied to range, so select a range, then go to address bar paste this formula and press **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**. In this particular case the range has to be in column shape.

I left the formula as not formatted text, so it was easier to copy.

=IF(INT(SQRT(MMULT((IF(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(INDIRECT(G4),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))))=MMULT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))),0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))^2),1+0*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))/COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4))))=SQRT(MMULT((IF(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(INDIRECT(G4),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))))=MMULT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))),0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))^2),1+0*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))/COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4))),SQRT(MMULT((IF(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(INDIRECT(G4),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))))=MMULT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))),0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))^2),1+0*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))/COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4))),"")

The formula could be read as

```
=IF(INT(A)=A,A, "")
```

where A is

```
SQRT(MMULT((IF(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(INDIRECT(G4),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))))=MMULT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))),1+0*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))),0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(INDIRECT(G4)))))^2),1+0*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))))/COUNTA(INDIRECT(G4)))
```